# Ruby could recognize the values when putting into a webpage text filed

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I have some values in my Excel as below:

```
1136-ΑΓΙΩΝ ΑΝΑΡΓΥΡΩΝ
1137-ΑΙΓΑΛΕΩ
```

But with script when I am putting those into a webpage filed, they are
saving into the field as below:

```
136-αΓ?Ω? α?α?Γ??Ω?
1137-α?Γα?εΩ
```

I am using Ruby 1.9.3 latest version. I am using win32ole library with 
Excel - 2010.

```
until number_of_list_values == 0

  number_of_list_values = number_of_list_values - 1
  element = driver.find_element :id => "codeExt"
  element.send_keys wbs.cells(rows,2).value
  element = driver.find_element :id => "descriptionExt"
  element.send_keys wbs.cells(rows,3).value
  driver.find_element(:name, "btnSaveandNew").click if 
number_of_list_values != 0
  wbs.cells(rows,5).value = "done"
  rows = rows + 1
  driver.find_element(:name, "btnSave").click if number_of_list_values 
== 0

end
```

Comment: I believe you need to set the [`codepage`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/win32ole/rdoc/WIN32OLE.html#method-c-codepage-3D). Unfortunately, I tried each of the standard codepages without success. What character set are those characters from?

Comment: @JustinKo Didn't get your point,my bad. I have an excel sheet from which i need to put those data into a webpage fields. But when I am doing manually it goes good,but via script they are producing and copied to the page as mentioned in the description.

Comment: You need to determine what character encoding you need to have those characters. Take a look at the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page). If you can figure out what encoding you need, you can solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to somehow set the proper encoding to read those values