# Not able get the label text incurred with <input> element

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I do have a below `HTML`:

```
<div id="filtersetedit_fieldNames" title="Please first select a list to filter!">
  <input value="5418630" name="NameID" type="checkbox"> John Das
  <input value="6360899" name="NameID" type="checkbox"> Ram Roy 
  <input value="9556609" name="NameID" type="checkbox"> Smith
  <input value="20156687" name="NameID" type="checkbox"> Paul
</div>
```

Now I have to click on the respective check-box using selenium-webdriver. But I tried to get extract the values as `John Das,Ram roy etc`. This is because just to get the index number to hit the check box.But my code didn't worked at all.

***`CODE`***

```
driver.find_elements(:id,"filtersetedit_fieldNames").each do |x|
  puts x.text
  #puts index
  break if x.text == "LocationAttributes:Currency Type"
  index = index + 1
end

driver.find_elements(:name, "candidateFieldIds")[index].click
```

But the values are printed as a String `"John Das Ram Roy Smith Paul"` from where I am confused how to find the proper index so that I can use that in my `check box` hitting code.

I am actually looking to create an array kind of things say it should come as `["John Das","Ram Roy","Smith","Paul"]`

Comment: Do you just want all of the text or do you also need to know the text in relation to the checkboxes?

Comment: @JustinKo Yes! you are right text in relation with the check box or at least the index number of the text, so that ican use some thing like that `driver.find_elements(:xpath,"//div[contains(@id,'filtersetedit_fieldNames')]/input[index numbner]").click`. After the search of the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your real goal is to set the checkbox based on the text (ie you do not actually need the array of names), you can use an xpath selector to find the checkbox element that is immediately followed by the desired text:

```
#The text of the checkbox you want to select
text_of_target_checkbox = 'Ram Roy'

#The div containing the checkboxes
checkbox_div = driver.find_element(:id => 'filtersetedit_fieldNames')

#Get the checkbox that has the specified text immediately after it
e = checkbox_div.find_element(:xpath => "./input            
    [following-sibling::text()
        [
            position() = 1 and 
            normalize-space(.)='#{text_of_target_checkbox}'
        ]
    ]")

#Click the checkbox
e.click
```

Comment: woww......Nice one but the logic you have set to find the desired `check box` is an extra ordinary one - atleast i have never seen. Really any doc would you like to suggest from where I can learn such kind of topics? please.. And do you have any personal blog also, if any please share - hope there also you have put lot's of good tips about ruby and anything based on ruby.

Comment: When it comes to selenium, I find it is good to learn about xpath and css selectors. There are plenty of resources for both online. You can find a link to my blog in my profile. However, it is relatively new and mostly geared towards the watir gems rather than selenium. While the two gems have common concepts, you would have to translate the watir code to selenium.

Comment: If i need anything to know,can I post anything there? is there any facility over there?

Comment: You mean on my blog? You can comment on posts if the question is related to the post. Otherwise, you are better of creating a question here on StackOverflow. If no one answers on StackOverflow, you are welcome to email me directly.

Comment: your email ID i don't know. here might people before reaching to you,killed my post.. :(

Comment: Can you help me in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714298/ruby-could-recognize-the-values-when-putting-into-a-webpage-text-filed/14714697#14714697) ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
driver.find_elements(
  :xpath,
  "//div[contains(@id,'filtersetedit_fieldNames')]/input"
) do |x|
```

should be:

```
driver.find_elements(
  :xpath,
  "//div[contains(@id,'filtersetedit_fieldNames')]/input"
).each do |x|
```